# docker React, django(gunicorn), nginx reverse proxy with https give Bad request 400 on accessing backend APIs

Tags: reactjs, django, docker, nginx, https

I have containerized application with following containers working together with docker-compose

1. Nginx - reverse proxy
2. React - frontend
3. Django served using gunicorn - backend

When using http all works well with frontend and backend. I used letsencrypt certbot to generate ssl certificates. On switching to https, fronend seems to work fine however none of backend apis are working. Any request to backend such as login generates 'Bad Request 400' response.
I have tried following options but none worked.

a. Switching Django to production and adding ALLOWED_HOSTS=['*'] or specific domain

b. Adding upstream in nginx.conf

c. disableHostCheck: true in webpack devServer.

Following are my docker-compose and nginx.conf respectively

docker-compose.yml

```
services:
    reverse_proxy:
        image: nginx:1.17.10
        volumes:
            - ./reverse_proxy/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
            - ./reverse_proxy/certbot-etc:/etc/letsencrypt
            - ./reverse_proxy/certbot-var:/var/lib/letsencrypt
        ports:
            - 80:80
            - 443:443
        depends_on:
            - webapp
            - frontend


    webapp:
        build : ./backend/

        command: gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 ai.wsgi:application
        expose:
            - 8000
        volumes:
            - ./backend/:/app
        ports:
            - 8000:8000


    frontend:
        build: ./frontend/ai-web/
        command: npm run ai
        ports:
            - 3000:3000
```

nginx.conf

```
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;



events {
        worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    fastcgi_read_timeout 3000;
    proxy_read_timeout 3000;
    client_max_body_size 1000M;


    upstream django {
             server webapp:8000;
             }

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name localhost 127.0.0.1;
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://frontend:3000;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        }

        location /api/ {
            proxy_pass http://webapp:8000;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        }
    }
     server {
           listen 443 ssl;
           server_name my_domain;
           ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://frontend:3000;
  proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto "https";
        }

        location /api/ {
            proxy_pass http://webapp:8000;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto "https";
            }

        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/my_domain/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/my_domain/privkey.pem;
        }
}
```

Am I missing opening container port while using https ?
Please provide any pointers.

Comment: Here you have tutorial Django+React+Docker https://saasitive.com/tutorial/docker-compose-django-react-nginx-let-s-encrypt/

Comment: @s007, did you got it fixed?

Comment: Yes, server firewall 443 port wasn't open.